# How to develop a p2p server based on JXTA2.X integrated with Tomcat(or other serlvet containers) using java？

Tags: java, cloud, p2p, jxta, fileserver

Basic requirements:

```
1. Build a file server (back is cloud-storage server)
2. Build satellite servers for private company
3. file server and satellite server shared file metadata and authorization.
```

I recognize p2p fit our requirements(not sure).

Currently, I just found the following tutorials:
[The JXTA solution to P2P](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1019-jxta.html?page=7) and book [Mastering JXTA](http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mastering%20jxta&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=ftp://92.241.233.90/pub/trashyard/library/DEV_BOOKZ/Java/Mastering%2520JXTA%2520%28Wiley%29.pdf&ei=t-qXT7mTCoig2AWBjbX8Bg&usg=AFQjCNE85kA2FyMJ7ytbLXC57PvRgoQ4mA).

Any suggestions are prompted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done something like that in [b2een](http://b2een.com/download.html) which is basically Jetty+JXTA+Other Stuff. Jetty handles the UI, REST, etc.. while JXTA handles the communication and data exchange between the b2een peers.

So, it is doable bue let me give you a couple of warnings:

1. A P2P network like JXTA is excellent at two things: handling non centralized networks ('direct' peer to peer communications) and jumping firewalls (via relays). If you have a star like network with central server(s) and remote clients, do not use P2P: you will have all the complexity of these networks without the benefits.
2. JXTA is not maintained anymore. Thanks to Oracle unwilling to release the name to the Open Source community, we were unable to move JXTA to the Apache foundation and the maintainers left.

Now, this being said, I have been programming for many (many) years, and working on p2p networks is definitely one of the most thrilling thing I have ever done.